# How to include HTML and CSS files in a chrome extension?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension. I have a small extension which includes CSS, javascript and HTML files. I want to run this extension on any web page, but `content_script` only allows me to run a script file. When I add `css` or `html` file extensions it doesn't work. It doesn't show the HTML page that I created for the extension, just `script.js`. How can I add and HTML file in `content_script`?

This is my `manifest.json` file:

```
{   
    "manifest_version":2,

    "name":"News Plugin",
    "description": "This extension will show you the latest news with headlines and small description",
    "version":"1.0",


    "browser_action":{
    "default_icon":"news_icon.png",
    "default_popup":"NewsApp.html"
    },
    //"chrome_url_overrides":{
    //"newtab":"NewsApp.html"
    //},

    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches":["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
            "js":["news.js"],
            "html":["news.js"],
            "css":["style.js"]
        }
    ],

    "permissions":[
    "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why do your HTML and CSS files have `.js` extensions?

Comment: And did you really mean to use the same file for both JS and HTML?

Comment: sorry i just copied the .js extension in css and html file. Yes i want to use single html file(which includes css and js reference files) in content script.

Comment: Improved some of the spelling, grammer, and formatting of the question. I also modified the tags - `jquery` isn't relevant here, `web` is too generic, and I added the `google-chrome-extension` and `css` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts for the specification of the `content_scripts` property in `manifest.json`. There's no `"html"` property in `content_scripts`. If it did allow injecting HTML, where would it put it, since the original page already has its own HTML? You can only add Javascript and CSS.

If you want to add HTML to the page, you'll need to do it in your Javascript, using DOM manipulation functions, which allow you to specify where the new elements should go.

Comment: Thank You so much:)